pyperformance is timing out
Trying to run pyperformance benchmark
https://pyperformance.readthedocs.io/usage.html#compile-python-to-run-benchmarks
Installed pyperformance python3 -m pip install pyperformance
Installed apt install pypy3
Not sure, if this is the right way. as apt install pypy-devel from documentation doesn't work.
Then I tried to run the benchmark. pyperformance run  -o py310.json
But it is failing with the following error. Proxy is set and no issues with installing any packages.
/home/pyperformance/venv/cpython3.10-eb1267903658-compat-af96b9431081/bin/python -m pip install -U 'setuptools>=18.5' wheel
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./venv/cpython3.10-eb1267903658-compat-af96b9431081/lib/python3.10/site-packages (59.6.0)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f989867b580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/setuptools/

